# Convert map image to 2d-array. Algorithm dfs,bfs, astar

Tags: java, image, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have problem how to start with this program.
I want to get 2d-array of pixel localization. 
Then work on this array with bfs, dfs to get path from orange dot to green dot.
Draw grey pixel if visited. 
Draw the path and save it to other image.

When i will handle with this i would like to change cost on each pixel (by drawing in paint something similar to walls but it could go throught by them with higher cost)

```
    public int [][] gRGB(BufferedImage image)
{
    int width = image.getWidth();
      int height = image.getHeight();
      int[][] result = new int[width][height];

      for (int row = 0; row < width; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < height; col++) {

            result[row][col] = image.getRGB(row, col);
         }
      }

      return result;
}
}
```

From this code i get 2d-array full of -1 value. Is there option to get color information as value (not rgb i would like to have it as one number not 4)

EDIT:

```
protected static int [][] convert(BufferedImage image)
{
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    int[][] result =  new int [width][height];

    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(col, row));
            String h = String.format("%02x%02x%02x", c.getRed(),c.getGreen(),c.getBlue());

            if(h.equals("000000"))     // black
            {
                result[col][row] = 0;
            }
            else if(h.equals("fe0000")) // red
            {
                result[col][row] = 5; 
            }
            else if(h.equals("ffffff")) // white
            {
                result[col][row] = 1;
            }
            else if(h.equals("ff7d41")) // orange - start
            {
                result[col][row] = 10;
            }
            else if (h.equals("ff0078")) // pink - end
            {
                result[col][row] = 9;
            }
            else
            {
                result[col][row] = 3;
            }

        }

    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(int col = 0; col < width; col++)
            System.out.print("\t" + result[col][row]);
    }

    return result;      
}
```

So i have now the array of pixel value. Can someone explain me how to write DFS or BFS algorithm?? Where the cost is the value of pixel?

[Black - walls, Orange dot - start, Green dot - end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Duj.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to find a path with minimum cost ?

Comment: Yes. Then draw the path on image. Where cost is color (White pixel - cost 1, red cost 5). But i dont know how to implement dfs or bfs on 2d array. result[col][row] and neighbor is result[col+1][row+1]....
And the end print the total cost of path

Answer (score 0):

For finding the path with minimum cost it is better to use algorithms such as UCS,A* or IDA* (It is very inefficient to use BFS or DFS to find shortest path on a weighted graph). My suggestion is to first implement UCS , then improve it with a simple heuristic such as manhattan distance to A*. For full explanation about UCS and A* please refer to these links:

[Wikipedia A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)
[Wikipedia UCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform-cost_search)

As for using these algorithms on your 2D-Array, you should consider every point a node and connect that node to every neighbor nodes. So every node is connected to its 4 non-wall neighbors ( or 8 non-wall neighbors if you can move diagonally ).

Comment: Ok , thanks for information. I will start with A* algorithm. Then i will try bfs and dfs implementation to test it.